# FACT_ACTIVITIES not being updated in Worklight

Tags: database, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Worklight project containing two applications: one Native and another Hybrid (web only).

The `APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT` table is being updated properly for both; However, the `FACT_ACTIVITIES` table is only being updated for the native application.

The hybrid application is very simple. Also, the "init" and "login" values are being written to `APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT.ACTIVITY` column, and it also logs using the `logActivity()` client JS function.

The Worklight report schedule seems to be writing the raw data appropriately, but not for both applications... Why aren't the native and hybrid application data being written to the `FACT_ACTIVITIES` table?

Answer (score 0):

You said "Hybrid (web only)".  By definition, a hybrid app is one whose UI is rendered using partly or fully HTML, but is wrapped in a native container, thus installed as though it was a native app on a device.  I assume by "(web only)" you mean it is accessible only by a web browser.

If my assumption is correct, then the behavior you describe is expected.  The APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT data that records activity originating from a browser is not recorded in the FACT_ACTIVITIES table.  This is by design.

As for the "why" question, I'd have to ask a Worklight architect.  :)

Comment: No, this is the usage of the tables.  It's my understanding that FACT_ACTIVITIES is a summary of data in APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT, the nightly process updates this table.  But, would be good to see some actual doc on this.